Gate Oxide vs. Source/Drain ESD protection
It's common practice to not tie VCC/GND directly to the gate of a MOSFET but use tie HI/LO cells instead in order to protect the thin gate oxide of the driven transistor in the event of unstable supply voltage levels. However, there doesn't seem to be a similar concern when VCC/GND is directly connected to the source/drain region. Doesn't the voltage spike negatively affect the durability of the diffusion as well, or just to an acceptable degree that it is not as critical as the gate oxide damage?

Please draw a schematic example.

Is this a VLSI question? I would suggest asking the fab; the reasons might be proprietary anyway.
